How can I write a kernel mode driver in C to manipulate inputs from a Dualshock4 controller?
I have been studying the in's and out's of driver development. I have gotten a working driver written that captures keyboard inputs by attaching my driver's device to "\Device\KeyboardClass0", however, those structures are known and KeyboardClass0 is universal. For gamepad controllers though, it is not universally designed.
I can build my driver successfully and install it, but if I use IoAttachDevice in my code, it says that the device is currently in use and I cannot attach to it. If I use IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStackSafe, then the system BSOD's. I also have not been using anything from the wdk.h library, but I want to.
How can I implement a safe way to attach my driver to my controller?
Would it be recommended that I write a driver that is lower level?
My basic end desire of a result is to map the analog stick input to a user-defined curve.
